# Search at dream weaver using regular expression

Tags: css, regex

Hello i am trying to find and replace all at Dreamweaver using regular expression.

My CSS:

```
.class1{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 2px 1px 0px 0px;
} 

.class2{
  position:relative
  float:left;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
```

Now i want to find all margin using regular expression and want to replace them by adding !important at the last.

Already i can find using regular expression by using this

```
margin:.*?;
```

Now i want to replace all margin with !important using regular expression at Dreamweaver.
example

```
margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px !important;
```

can anybody give solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested in DW CS6**

Search: `margin:((?:\s*\d+px)+)\s*;`

Replace: `margin:$1 !important;`

I made the regex a bit specific so we don't add `!important` when we already have `!important` :)